# How do I know how an image will look on a website?

Tags: image, css

Is there specific data about an image that allows you to know how it will look in a browser? Every site I visit has clear, crisp, beautiful images, but whenever I add one to a site I've created it almost always looks pixelated or gets cut off.

Comment: Show us some examples on how you embed your images so we can give concrete advice.

Answer (score 2):

"Crispness" is a very subjective term but here's what I suggest:

- Make sure your images that don't need transparency are jpg, otherwise use png for images with transparency
- Images are 72ppi
- Images are optimised with something like ImageOptim at say 80%
- Don't resize images in the browser as much as you can, this can cause blurriness

[Lots of great tips here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/optimize-images).

Comment: DPI is only useful for print and basically irrelevant for the web. You need a certain resolution - yes, but that is independent from DPI and also heavily depends on your usecase. Image compression (done by "you") and scaling (done by the browser) are the biggest factors for image quality.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `SVG` for everything that you can (icons/ logos/ patterns) and for normal "photos" use optimized `.png`. Keep an eye out for the newer `.webp` image format (it's much faster then `.png`) but it's [not available](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=webp) in all browsers yet.

A good place to check out would be **Google's Material Design** spec.
https://material.io/design/

Comment: scalable vector graphics are always a good advice. `.webp` does not have sufficient support imho - at least as of now...https://caniuse.com/#search=webp I'd rather go for "oldfashioned" `jpg`.

Comment: I updated my answer